# Is there a picturebox.graphics() winforms equivalent to imagebox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

so i have this lines of codes from winforms that i would like to convert it to WPF. Now i am currently stuck for this function. Below is the code that i need to convert from winforms to WPF since WPF don't have the picturebox tools.

```
             Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
             g.Clear(Color.AliceBlue);
             pictureBox1.Image = newimage;//Image.FromFile(thumb);
```

I tried to swap the `picturebox1.CreatedGraphics()` to imagebox tool but it didnt have the createdgraphics function in it.

Would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the use of this: `Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics(); g.Clear(Color.AliceBlue);`? Can't you just set `pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue`? `Image` (if that's what you're referring to) has no background, you can create one with a Grid, a Border or other. Use its `Source` property to specify an ImageSource or a Resource.

Comment: since it's not really my code and my work is to convert it from winforms to WPF, i assumed that it will set a box or placeholder to put the image file (newimage) . which may explain the picturebox1.image = newimage. correct me if im wrong.

Comment: The only *possible* use of that code is to change the Color of the Control's background without triggering the Paint event (as mentioned, is the same `pictureBox1.BackColor = [Some Color]`, which will instead raise the Paint event). Which is rendered mute as soon as you set a new Image (it will raise the Paint event immediately). Or you invalidate the Form or the Control itself in any way. i.e., useless and a waste of graphics resources if you don't call `g.Dispose()` right after and you don't dispose of the previous Image (if one was assigned, of course). Anyway, not your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you need to to:

1. Create a Border and set `Background` to `Colors.AliceBlue`
2. Create an `Image` named `pictureBox1` as a child to the `Border` and set `Source = new BitmapImage(new Url(path-to-image))`

i.e

```
<Border Background="AliceBlue">
 <Image Source = "path-to-image"/>
</Border>
```